# Pycharm перестал видеть список управления модулями( pip, pip3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

Pycharm перестал видеть список управления модулями(pip, pip3)
и не видит обновлени и не устанавливает не чего
[image: Это список установленых пакетов]
вот такая беда 
[image: это что получаеться]

os (Ubuntu 15.04)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Друзья, коллеги,  разобрался сам ,

Дело в том, что при обновлении с  Pycharm 4.5.3 на 4.5.4, не обновился  ssl для  Java.
Лог ругался как-то так:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty         at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.<init>(PKIXValidator.java:90)
```

Обновил так:

```
sudo update-ca-certificates -f
```

А для гарантии так:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates-java
```

И всё  заработало. Всем Спасибо.